# Движение по кругу (CSS3)

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

У меня вопрос по поводу того как синхронизировать анимации @keyframes.
Есть планета, которая вращается по кругу. Мне хочется добавить ещё одну, но с другой точкой старта. Однако, получается, что анимации выполняются последовательно и одна планета накладывается на другую, а точка старта меняется скачкообразно. Как это можно исправить? И ещё подскажите, как сделать чтобы вращающаяся планета была привязана к центральной не вылетала с орбиты при изменении размера окна.

[image: cosmos]

```css
html {
  height:100%;
}
body {
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
  
  /*контент в центр страницы*/
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  margin: 33% 33% 33% 33%;
  background: radial-gradient(#60AAFE, #0455F1, #D86AF7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.circle1,
.circle2 {
  background: radial-gradient(#60AAFE, #0455F1, #D86AF7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 8%;
  transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px) rotate(180deg);
}

/*при наведении на фигуру*/
.circle:hover,
.circle1:hover,
.circle2:hover {
  box-shadow: inset #57A8FA 0 0 40px 10px,
              #57A8FA 0 0 24px 12px;
}

.donut {
  border: 1px solid  #F0FFFF;
  border-radius: 150px;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  box-shadow: inset #57A8FA 0 0 20px 5px,
              #57A8FA 0 0 22px 7px;
}

.orbit1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 33%;
  
  animation: Orbita 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes Orbita {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  }
}

.orbit2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 33%;
  left: 39%;
  top: 29%;
  bottom: 33%;

  animation: Orbita 15s linear infinite; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes Orbita {
  from { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to   { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="donut">
  <figure class="circle1 circle1-pos orbit1"></figure>
  <figure class="circle2 circle2-pos orbit2"></figure>
  <figure class="circle"></figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
@keyframes Orbita2 {
    from { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(150px) rotate(180deg); }
    to   { transform: rotate(540deg) translateX(150px) rotate(540deg); }
}

.orbit2 {
    animation: Orbita2 15s linear infinite;
}
```

Итого:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
}
body {
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
  
  /*контент в центр страницы*/
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  margin: 33% 33% 33% 33%;
  background: radial-gradient(#60AAFE, #0455F1, #D86AF7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.circle1,
.circle2 {
  background: radial-gradient(#60AAFE, #0455F1, #D86AF7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 8%;
  transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px) rotate(180deg);
}

/*при наведении на фигуру*/
.circle:hover,
.circle1:hover,
.circle2:hover {
  box-shadow: inset #57A8FA 0 0 40px 10px,
              #57A8FA 0 0 24px 12px;
}

.donut {
  border: 1px solid  #F0FFFF;
  border-radius: 150px;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  box-shadow: inset #57A8FA 0 0 20px 5px,
              #57A8FA 0 0 22px 7px;
}

.orbit1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 33%;
  
  animation: Orbita 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes Orbita {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes Orbita2 {
    from { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(150px) rotate(180deg); }
    to   { transform: rotate(540deg) translateX(150px) rotate(540deg); }
}

.orbit2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 33%;
  left: 39%;
  top: 29%;
  bottom: 33%;
  animation: Orbita2 15s linear infinite; 
}
```

```html
<div class="donut">
  <figure class="circle1 circle1-pos orbit1"></figure>
  <figure class="circle2 circle2-pos orbit2"></figure>
  <figure class="circle"></figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну сниппет что ли... И выпили `-webkit`.

Comment: Спасибо, копипастил у автора. Сниппет будет на 99% как в вопросе, потому не стал добавлять.

Comment: Но его можно без усилий запустить. Кстати, можно свёрнутый по умолчанию добавить.

Comment: Ага, вроде получилось

Comment: Хм.. Я думал, в вопросе просят орбиту исправить на нарисованный круг, а не только второй спутник добавить?

Comment: Спасибо. Keyframes я переделал по-другому, но ваш ответ очень помог. С орбитой тоже справился.